# How to increase the size of the dataframe by 5 times using pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which has about 5 million rows. How do I programmatically increase the size of the dataframe by 5 times to do some performance testing. Below is the example of the dataframe. The combination of the id_nbr, id_itm and id_line makes each row unique. I want to increase the size of this dataframe by 5-fold by populating the unique id_nbrs programatically. Can someone pls help me how to go about it.

```
id_nbr        id_itm      id_line        col4          col5
50000001      100           101
50000001      100           102
50000002      200           201
50000002      200           202
50000007      100           101
50000020      300           301
50000021      300           301
```

Answer (score 2):

You can union the same dataframe 5 times ex:

```
df.union(df).union(df).union(df).union(df)
```

If you want a unique ID column and not have double values, you can add a constant value to that column for each dataframe, ex:

```
df.union(df.withColumn("id", col("id") + 5)).union(df.withColumn("id", col("id") + 15)).union(df.withColumn("id", col("id") + 25)).union(df.withColumn("id", col("id") + 25))
```

Of course, you can adjust the constant value depending from your id column values to make sure not having same values.

If you are not sure how to choose the contant value you can get the max value of the id column in your dataframe lets call it mx, then for each dataframe add mx, then 2 * mx, then 3*mx ... then 5 * mx, this will guarantee unique values.

Comment: I want to maintain the uniqueness of the ids meaning if i union it the ids wont change it'll have the same id. so ideally in the example we have 7 rows of ids and id_lines combination. the next 7 should be different from the original 7 . So when I 5 fold this I'd have 35 unique id and id_line combinations. Union wont help this use case I think

Comment: awesome let me try this out. Would this also work in a huge data frame where there are like 5million records and that needs to be exploded by 5 fold to say 25 million ?

Comment: to get the max ? the max is kind of fast operation in apache spark so it should past, however multiplying your date by 5 could decrease the performance it depends from your cluster ressources and the transformation you want to apply